# Deleting an array of pointers without a specified size

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, delete-operator

I can't figure out why the following C++ code compiled in VS2013 results in a crash.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class A {};

void main()
{
    A** arr1 = new A*[5] { new A(), new A(), new A(), new A(), new A() };
    delete[] arr1;
    A** arr2 = new A*[] { new A(), new A(), new A(), new A(), new A() };
    delete[] arr2;
}
```

The first array gets initialized and deleted correctly, but the second results in a "%Filename%.exe has triggered a breakpoint" exception on the `delete[] arr2` line followed by a debug assertion:

```
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c
Line: 1322

Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)
```

The difference between these two arrays is quite obvious: one has an explicitly specified length, the other doesn't. But isn't the compiler supposed to be clever enough to determine the length from the number of items in the following initializer list? Because it does that just fine if the array consists of raw objects (i.e. `A* arr = new A[] { A(), A(), A() }`).

Please point me to what I'm doing wrong or explain the reason behind this.

*Disregard the memory leaks from the array items. They get deleted in the real program, this one was quickly thrown together for a demonstration. The crash occurs either way.*

Comment: In both cases, don't you have to loop through the array and `delete` each index and then `delete[]` the array pointer itself.. -- Sorry did not see `disregard the memory leaks`. Weird, the second declaration of the array doesn't compile for me in Mingw 4.8.1.

Comment: VS2013 compiles it just fine. VS2008, on the other hand, refuses to compile both array initialization lines. Could it be that this issue appeared as a result of added C++11 support in VS2013?

Comment: I wonder if `new A*[]` is even legal...

Answer (score 1):

To see what's really going on, I tried overloading the `new` and `delete` operators. I tried overloading `new[]` and `delete[]` however VS2013 says it's already defined in some .lib file.. so the following will have to do.. (Mind you I have never overloaded new or delete before so I hope this is right)

This is a 32 bit program where `sizeof(int) = 4`.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

void* operator new(std::size_t size) //this is called..
{
    std::cout << "Allocated: "<<size<<"\n";
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr) //this function never gets called.
{
    std::cout << "DeAllocated\n";
    free(ptr);
}

int main()
{
    int** arr1 = new int*[2] {new int(1), new int(2)};
    delete[] arr1;

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    int** arr2 = new int*[] {new int(3), new int(4)};
    delete[] arr2;
}
```

The results are:

```
Allocated: 8
Allocated: 4
Allocated: 4


Allocated: 0
Allocated: 4
Allocated: 4
```

So where does that 8 come from? Hmm?

Let's change the first example to:

```
int** arr1 = new int*[3] {new int(1), new int(2), new int(3)};
```

and the second to:

```
int** arr2 = new int*[] {new int(4), new int(5), new int(6)};
```

The results are now:

```
Allocated: 12
Allocated: 4
Allocated: 4
Allocated: 4


Allocated: 0
Allocated: 4
Allocated: 4
Allocated: 4
```

Do you see what is happening now? The second seems to be allocating the wrong size. In other words, I think it says that arr2 is of size 0 whereas arr1 is of size 12.. Just a guess at what my results say lol.

Comment: So `[]` is being treated as `[0]`... Which is pretty strange in my opinion. But why would `A* arr = new A[] { A(), A(), A(), A(), A() }; delete[] arr;` (which still outputs `Allocated: 0`, by the way) be deleted without any problems?

Comment: It does not work for that. `int* arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` and `delete[] arr;` crashes the same way in VS2013.. Well for me at least. Even without overloading `new` and `delete` it crashes. :S Something about `Heap Corruption` and writing to the end of array of size 0. Again this also compiles in VS2013 but not gcc/g++/mingw 4.8.1

Comment: Indeed, it does crashes with `int`, but doesn't crash with my `class A { };` or even `class A { int value; }` (just to rule out the possibility that the issue is because of an empty class).

Comment: You are indeed right.. I used `std::cout<<"Constructed A\n";` in A's constructor.. It works and I have no clue why.

Answer (score 0):

g++ 2.8.1 won't compile arr2:

```
foo8.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo8.cpp:7:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
     A** arr2 = new A*[] { new A(), new A(), new A(), new A(), new A() };
                   ^
foo8.cpp:7:71: error: too many initializers for ‘A* [1]’
     A** arr2 = new A*[] { new A(), new A(), new A(), new A(), new A() };
```

Taken with what @CantChooseUsernames found, I guess there is something subtle about c++11 I'm missing, I don't understand why that (in terms of the initializer list) is a different case from:

```
A arr3[] {A(),A(),A()};
```

which compiles just fine.